# Classes not loading when integrating the Paypal Adaptive Payments SDK

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I have been trying to implement Paypal's adaptive payments sdk provided on github, and I am trying to work out one of the simple samples provided on the github page for chained payments (https://github.com/paypal/adaptivepayments-sdk-php/blob/master/samples/SimpleSamples/ChainedPay.php)

I have updated the Configuration.php file and I have installed the sdk on my local apache server using composer. When I updated the top two lines of the chained payments example on github to:

`require_once('/includes/adaptivepayments-sdk-php-3.6.106/samples/vendor/autoload.php');
require_once('/includes/adaptivepayments-sdk-php-3.6.106/samples/Common/Constants.php');`

I know it loads the autoload.php, autoload_real,php, ClassLoader.php, and autoload_namespaces.php files. However, My webpage still throws this error:

`"Fatal error: Class 'Receiver' not found in \...\views\paypal_try.php on line 25"`

And I am not sure why the class (or any other ones, I believe) is not being loaded. Any information and/or guidance on how to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just worked this out yesterday.  You'll need a few things:

1. Composer setup
2. The `namespace-php5.3` branch checked out with Composer

Looks like it's doable, but boy their repo (and code) is a mess.